# There's a black square when I render alpha channel in Cycles but not in Eevee

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, image, transparency

There's a black square when I render alpha channel that casts onto another alpha channel in cycles:

[image: picture]
Notice how the leaves that is over the 'earth' has black squares behind them.

It only happens because the 'earth' has a layer of 'clouds.png'

[image: cloud node]
[image: leaf node]
When I tried to render the leaves onto solid objects, the black squares dissapeared. Any ideas on this?

Note that this worked fine on Eevee render:
because it has the settings to change blend mode in the material panel.

[image: eeveeRender]

Comment: There are blend modes under "viewport display" in the material properties panel, but I'm not sure if they affect only the viewport, or the render as well.

Comment: Try increasing the value for transparent bounces